# What happens if I override `window.URL`

Tags: javascript, url

I've created a custom URL object in JavaScript and discovered that Firefox already has an object at `window.URL` of type `MozURL`. I haven't noticed any other browser setting `window.URL`, so I'd like to know the following things:

- Are there any unexpected consequences of overriding `window.URL` with my own object
- What is `window.URL` used for in Firefox?
- Are there *any* other browsers that also set `window.URL` to their own object<sup>1</sup>

My back-up plan is of course to use a namespacing object, but I'd rather be able to write `new URL()` instead of `new foo.URL()`.

<sub>[1] this is, of course, subject to change with later versions of browsers so remember to note the dates on any answers</sub>

---

#### edit to add:

I just had the thought of naming the object `URI` instead of `URL`, but even so I'll probably stick to namespacing to avoid possible future conflicts with `URI`.

Comment: It's from a proposed W3C spec: http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/#URL-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's new in Firefox 4, and part of a W3C working draft for the [File API](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/#URL-object).

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.URL):

> Provides methods used for creating object URLs.

You could change it; if you wanted - but it might become an API that you will want to use later. It might also surprise other developers that `URL` isn't what they expect it to be. I'd suggest going with the namespace solution.