# Approach for sniffing Firefox 4 and higher

Tags: javascript, firefox4, browser-detection

I am writing a JavaScript library that **must** check for Firefox 4 or higher. Trust me, I need to.

I'm planning to go with the following sniffing code:

```
if ('MozAppearance' in document.documentElement.style) {

    //We have Mozilla

    if (!!window.FormData) {

        //We have Firefox4+

    }
}
```

I feel ok about it because it seems rather unlikely (to me) that anyone will add a global FormData method.

Assuming I'm comfortable with the usual risks associated with any browser sniffing method, can you see any problems with this?

Documentation for window.FormData in Firefox is here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData

Thanks!

Comment: But *why* do you need to check for Firefox 4 or higher? It's possible (however unlikely) that you haven't considered a better approach.

Comment: I'm interested just to know why FF4?!

Comment: I'm writing a browser with a Window.FormData method...just to defeat this.  Think I'll name it "NOT FF4".  Catchy, no?

Comment: The 'why' is not important. It's beside the point, but since I know you folks can't rest until you know why...here it is. A plugin object this library supports needs DOM manipulation in FF4+ on Mac, because of changes in FF's code that this plugin relied upon. It's real-world nastiness, but that's how it is. If you have never had to sniff and you think 'there must be a better way', let me know. I think we can all agree that the above method is better than testing a regexp against navigator.userAgent, right?

Answer (score 0):

That's up to you to decide if that is reasonable feature detection for you. If you believe that testing for the presence of `FormData` is enough; then go with that.

You can "increase" the features you check for as well. You can also look for `window.URL`, a [new feature in Firefox 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043411/what-happens-if-i-override-window-url/7043471#7043471) as well:

```
if (!!window.FormData && !!window.URL) {

    //We have Firefox4+

}
```

So now your odds that someone declared *both* are even lower. You could also get the user-agent involved as well if you trust your users enough to not change them.

Comment: I like your approach of combining tests to lower the chance of false positives in the wild. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

window.history.pushState is another one you can check.
I think we could do this all day with features that appear in FF4+ but not FF3.x.

Answer (score 0):

> Assuming I'm comfortable with the usual risks associated with any
>   browser sniffing method, can you see any problems with this?

It will break the moment they drop the prefix.
All the [`-moz-` properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS_Reference/Mozilla_Extensions) tagged obsolete attest of that fact.
So remember you will have to continually add recent Mozilla extensions using `||`.

Comment: -moz-appearance is part of the XUL platform for rendering an element using a native control based on the operating system. It's extremely unlikely that this will ever be standardized; so the prefix will always be there.